# Who gets the points when calling Muggins in a three-player Cribbage game?

Tags: cribbage

If two players call "Muggins" at the same time (in a three-player Cribbage game), and both players call the correct number of points, which player is awarded the points?

I have looked at several sources but found nothing ([ACC](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/), Pagat.com, [The House of Cards](http://www.thehouseofcards.com/rules/cribbage-rules.html) and more).

In the meantime, my friends and I have made a list of 3 possible solutions and we are "evaluating" them:

1. Both players are awarded the points;
2. Each player is awarded only half the points (rounding to the upper value);
3. The player to the left (from the underpegging player) is awarded the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whomever calls it scores it. The rules at [American Cribbage Congress](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/default.asp) do not address muggins outside of 2 player, but the wording requires that it be called before pegging it. Since, in 3 player, there is a dealer, a pone, and another pone, it's simplest to let whomever caught it score it.

Further, in 30 years of playing cribbage, in both 3 and 4 hand, whomever catches it claims the points. This is incentive to pay attention to opponent play and score calls.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite addresses the question.  The question is about what to do if two or more players simultaneously call Muggins.  In such a case, multiple people have "caught it" - so, who gets to score it?  I'm sure this is a very rare case, but it is the root of the question here.

Comment: Player order is how I've always resolved that, but noting that the partner is ineligible to actually score the muggins, but it prevents losing the points.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing 3 player games with my kids.  Since there is no direct wording in the rules, this is what we agreed upon.

In the event of a muggin, the player next to score catches what he can. Then the third any missed by the others.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find any reference for this either, and I never play with Muggins, but I think the answer is fairly clearly your option 1. I'll go through the thought process.

Cribbage is basically a race, Muggins is a penalty for sloppy play and missing your point count. In a two player game, the penalty takes the form of your opponent getting the points instead of you. In a three player game:

#### In scenario #1

The player who missed the points is still "behind" by the same amount whether one or both of his opponents get the points. So it doesn't matter much if both players get the points.

#### In scenario #2

The player who missed the points is penalized more if only one opponent notices compared to if both opponents notice. Why?

#### In scenario #3

If only one opponent is awarded the points and gains the advantage, even though the other opponent also noticed, the other opponent is penalized as much as the player who missed the points. Why?

Unless there are good answers to my "why?" for #2 and #3, I think the only fair way to call Muggins is to award both players the points.